# Constantly check for internet connectivity in webview for IOS

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiviewcontroller

I already have the script for checking for an internet connection in the `viewDidLoad` like below which works great. If there is a connection is loads the url and if not it loads a local html page with a pretty picture telling the user that there internet is down.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.viewController = self

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    if CheckInternet.Connection() {

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/")
        let URLrequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.webView.load(URLrequest)

    } else {

        let htmlpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "nointernet", ofType: "html")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlpath!)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.webView.load(request)

    }

}
```

Problem is that if the users device loses an internet connection while they are using my app then it just hangs. I want to be able to have the app switch to the local html page automatically as soon as the connection is lost and switch back to the html (example.com) when the connection comes back online.

I have tried several different functions but none of them work. Is there an event that is triggered when the network connectivity changes on the users device that I could use my existing code?

Comment: Here's an option if you're able to use 3rd party frameworks. https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Comment: I already have something similar to reachability and working, what I am asking is that I need a something that constantly checks for the connection to the internet. So if they are currently using my app and the device loses connection is switches to the nointernet page.

Comment: That framework has an observer you can configure, which is why I suggested it. You've just got to configure the observer and what to do if you lose connectivity.

Comment: I love you....going to switch to that right now. Ill update on my progress. I didn't know about the observer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Adrian. Got it all workin with Reachability!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it squared away.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)

1.Install it via Pod:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
```

2.Variable declaration in your `UIViewController`

```
let reachability = Reachability()
```

3.Add observers and start the observer

```
// connected observer
reachability?.whenReachable = { reachability in
  // Connected to Internet
}

// disconnected observer
reachability?.whenUnreachable = { _ in
  // Not Connected to Internet
}
// start reachability observer
do {
  try reachability?.startNotifier()
} catch {
  print("Unable to start notifier")
}
```

4.Before disappering your `UIViewController`, stop the observer:

```
reachability?.stopNotifier()
```

Comment: Yeah I already discovered that and went with Reachability. Works great